# dynamically add children to component, then dynamically manipulate them?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

i dont know why this doesnt work. i have a tabnavigator which i dynamically add a navigatecontainer to which has a textarea dynamically added to the nav container. the id's of both have the same stringname as the chatguys[c][0].
it gives errors saying 'TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert spark.skins.spark::SkinnableContainerSkin@9737851 to spark.components.TextArea." at runtime. wut do?

any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you :(

```
                            var idx:uint;
            const len:uint = navigate.numChildren;

            var alreadyexists:Boolean = false;
            for (idx = 0; idx < len; idx++) {
                //var check:spark.components.TextArea = navigate.getElementAt(idx) as spark.components.TextArea;
                //var check:Tab = navigate.getTabAt(idx) as Tab;
                var check:NavigatorContent = navigate.getChildAt(idx) as NavigatorContent;

                // var check = navigate.getElementAt(idx);
                //elmt.selected = tgBtn.selected;

                if (check.label == evt.username)
                {// trace(navigate.getChildAt(idx).label);

                    var c:uint;
                    const p:uint = chatguys.length;
                    for (c = 0; c < p; c++){
                    if(chatguys[c][0] == evt.username){


                        spark.components.TextArea(DisplayObjectContainer(navigate.getChildAt(idx)).getChildAt(chatguys[c][0])).textFlow=TextConverter.importToFlow(chatguys[c][1], TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
                         }}
```

b here ill show you the second half which works fine, but maybe i need to do it differently to get waht i need done ?

```
 var chats:Array = [];
        var chatguys:Array = [];

        public function userlist_click() :void{
            var windowname:Object =users_lst.selectedItem;
                            var idx:uint;
                 const len:uint = navigate.numChildren;
                 trace(navigate.numChildren);
                 var alreadyexists:Boolean = false;
                 for (idx = 0; idx < len; idx++) {


                    var check:NavigatorContent = navigate.getChildAt(idx) as NavigatorContent;



                     if (check.label == windowname.name)
                             {
                             alreadyexists = true;
                             }
                 } 
                 if (alreadyexists == false)
                 {

                 chats[windowname.name] = new spark.components.TextArea();
                 chats[windowname.name].x = 10;
                 chats[windowname.name].y= 32; 
                 chats[windowname.name].width= 517.19696 ;
                 chats[windowname.name].height= 343.18182;
                 chats[windowname.name].scroller
                 chats[windowname.name].x="9";
                 chats[windowname.name].y="2";
                 chats[windowname.name].width="517.19696";
                 chats[windowname.name].height="343.18182";

                 chats[windowname.name].setStyle("skinClass", spark.skins.spark.TextAreaSkin);
                 //textArea.skinClass= "spark.skins.spark.TextAreaSkin";
                 chats[windowname.name].text="ffg";
                 chats[windowname.name].setStyle("verticalScrollPolicy", ScrollPolicy.ON);

                 var match = new Array();
                 match.push(windowname.name);
                 match.push('bob');
                 chatguys.push(match);
               for (var i in chatguys){
                   if (chatguys[i][0] == windowname.name){
                 chats[windowname.name].textFlow=TextConverter.importToFlow(chatguys[i][1], TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
               }}

                 chats[windowname.name].id = windowname.name;
                 trace(chats[windowname.name]);

                 var messagebox:NavigatorContent = new NavigatorContent;
                 messagebox.percentWidth= 100;
                 messagebox.percentHeight= 100;
                 messagebox.label = chats[windowname.name];
                 messagebox.id = chats[windowname.name];
                 trace(messagebox.label);
                 messagebox.addElement(chats[windowname.name]);
                 navigate.addChild(messagebox); }}
```

Comment: the error should also tell you the line number, please tell us what is the line (in the code you posted) that causes the error/

Comment: spark.components.TextArea(DisplayObjectContainer(navigate.getChildAt(idx)).getChildAt(chatguys[c][0])).textFlow=TextConverter.importToFlow(chatguys[c][1], TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
is the only possible place it could be as thats the only place where im attempting to access the textarea, for some reason its not grabbing the textarea but the spark skinnable container. mind boggling

also, anything else that you see that i might be doing wrong or that theres a better way to do it i would appreciate it if you shared or showed me.

Comment: IF, for whatever reason someone else somehow finds them selves doing what i was doing, to save you googling trouble heres the solution(and the answer to life)

       spark.components.TextArea(spark.components.NavigatorContent(DisplayObjectContainer(navigate.getChildAt(idx))).getElementAt(0)).textFlow=TextConverter.importToFlow(chatguys[c][1], TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);


<3 typhoid